# Adding a constraint to check another table whether if the data exists

Tags: sql-server

currently I'm learning SQL but i got stucked at one point, I've searched a number of threads but it seems that i can't find the exact one that I'm trying to achieve.

Currently after creating table, basically we can add constraints to add specific rules into it, however i can't seem to find out how.

basically it's like for example i have 2 tables currently. Table A (A_1,A_2 as the columns), and Table B (B_1) being the columns.

currently i wanted to add a constraint where if TableB.B_1 has the value there, example CODE001, then only it'll be able to add in A_1.

I read alot online saying that it'll require to add a check similar to check(tableB(B_1) = 1) but i'm not sure where to head to next.

Would be great if someone could guide me through on this part. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I could be mis-reading it, but what you're describing sounds a lot more like a Foreign Key constraint than a Check constraint.  Again, I read the question as A.A_1 can only be added if that entry exists in B.B_1.  As an Alter statement:

```
ALTER TABLE A
ADD CONSTRAINT A_B_FK FOREIGN KEY (A_2) REFERENCES B(B_1)
```

A Check constraint is similar, but typically not used to compare against data in another table like a foreign key is used for.  Now you could write a Check constraint around a function that included a table query, for example, if that's really what you need (see examples on TechNet - [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)).